# onserverclick not firing for input of type date

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I am building a web application in ASP.NET using webforms.

I have an input html element which I have set to run at server and I want to fire an event whenever the date is changed.

```
<input id="datePicker" class="form-control" style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; width: 15%; text-align: center;" type="date" runat="server" onserverclick="Date_Changed"/>
```

I have the event in my codebehind:

```
protected void Date_Changed(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
```

However, the event is never fired.

Answer (score 0):

Don't believe that server side click events can be wired up to a input that way (using the onserverclick).

I would consider dropping in a HTML button, say like this:

```
<button id="datePicker" 
 class="form-control" 
 style="display: inline; margin-left: 5px; width: 15%; text-align: center;" 
 type="date" 
 runat="server" onserverclick="Date_Changed" />
```

And even better yet, drop in a asp.net button.

If you drop in a input tag, then I don't think you can get the asp.net system to wire this up for you. You could I suppose write this:

(this is what a plane jane above button becomes:

```
<input onclick="__doPostBack('Button11','')" 
 name="Button11" type="button" id="Button11" value="button">
```

So you could try above - but using a "input" tag I don't believe will work, but try a HTML button as per above - that does allow "on server click".

Do keep in mind that if you drop in a asp.net text box, and set textmode = "date"?

Say like this:

```
        <asp:TextBox ID="MyDateTest" runat="server" TextMode="date">
        </asp:TextBox>
```

Then you see this:

[image]

So, above is a built in feature - you don't need any js, bootstrap, or anything at all.

but, you could add a "client" side click to your markup, as I posted a above the do post-back would (should) run your click event. However, it probably a whole lot better to not fight asp.net, since then you quite much hand coding a lot of HTML, and doing that means you quite much toss out most of the features of why you would use asp.net in the the first place (that means to take advantage of all the built in controls, and the pre-processing of those controls for you).